# Switching by use of transistor or relay

Tags: switches

I want to design a control module. In my circuit I am using relay for switching .now I again came across some information which said switching in a circuit is better dine by transistors because they are faster than relay .relay can do 50 ms while transistor 10 pico .now I want a transistor circuit that can work like a relay ?

Comment: Well, it really depends what you are switching. Faster is not always better. What do you realistically need to switch in 10ps? (This is very difficult.) Please give some details of the application. See also [(18858)](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18858/equivalent-circuit-of-a-solid-state-relay).

Comment: "Control module" = "thing" = "meaningless".

Comment: For switching high power levels relays generally have far lower losses due to the low resistance paths able to be provided. To be more specific you MUST give many more details.

Answer (score 1):

Transistor Vs relay, is like Horse Vs elephant, or Knight Vs bishop.
In other words, you'll see both being used for some time .The Relay, is more idiot proof, offers galvanic isolation and makes getting product approvals less problematic, and generally its voltage drop at high currents is lower, meaning less heat. But the relay is slow and has a limited number of operations and uses more space. The use of relay or transistor depends on the application requirements.

Comment: I thanks for this information .I intend to use circuit to operate two solenoid switches in an hydraulics which will actuating an actuator (cylinder spring applied hydraulics released). The operations is like the abs control module