# Solid state relay (or equivalent/alternative) to drive 6V DC from a 3.3V micro

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, solid-state-relay, 3.3v

I have to open/close two wire from a closed device. I cannot open due to it's under warranty, and the only part that I can open and modify is an external button that connects the two wires.

Firstly I wrongly thought that I can simulate the button press ion with only optocoupler ([4N25](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf)), but thanks to [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/6544/1335) I understood that this piece of hardware is not only an opto-isolator but an opto-transistor: it is better to use a SSR instead (a mechanical relay will not work because of the noisy "tick"). I don't have the GND signal but only `Vcc` and `Vo` (thanks to [Peter R. Bloomfield](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/42/peter-r-bloomfield) for this elucidation).

Just to recap, my needs, I have in one side an [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) that runs at 3.3V. In the other side of the circuit I have a signal that, when closed has 0-6V.

I have seen some other questions about how to simulate a SSR like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7516/why-do-solid-state-relays-cost-so-much) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18858/equivalent-circuit-of-a-solid-state-relay) bit as I got this is not tailored to my case: I don't need a zero-cross detection because I have to drive a DC circuit, and I need to drive it from Arduino Due that runs at 3.3V.

What can I do? Are there some cheap SSR that fit my 3.3V driver and DC lead? Is there some simple opto-isolator that I can use without the GND signal (no opto-transistor)? Or something I can add to the 4N25 that I already tried? Is there some other alternatives that I ignore?

Please sorry my entry level in the electronics so correct me in terminology if I have used unsuitable words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used a Photovoltaic relay for this in an Arduino driven application, the [IR PVT312](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/pvt312.pdf).

It is designed to work as a substitute for a Relay, and is rated to switch up to 250V at 190mA. It is suitable for AC and DC switching.

As you can see from the diagrams below, it's an opto-isolated MOSFET switch.

[image]

Comment: this seems to be perfect thanks, I will look into it!

Comment: Then another question, with the 190mA do you mean the driving circuit or the load?

Comment: @nkint The load. 190mA in 'A' connection, 210mA in 'B', 320mA in 'C'.

Comment: it seems to me that it is not so much. thank you anyway!

Comment: last thing: is it possible to drive it directly from a 3.3v arduino right? it is only an led.. I don't need any driving transistor neither a resistance, right?

Comment: @nkint It can be driven directly from a 3.3V Arduino, no transistor required, a 100 Ohm resistor in series would be advisable. At 6V 320mA is 1.8 Watts ; that's a reasonable amount of power. At 240VAC it can drive 240V x 190mA = 45 Watts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a small reed relay. This way you avoid a small voltage drops on solid state relays but it uses more power.

If reed relay is not fast enough for switch it on/off, look for DC voltage solid state relay ICs. Plenty of these to choose from.

Comment: Can you advice me some models please?